# Keep Quasar tooltip open when mouse on the tooltip

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, quasar-framework, quasar

I’m using tooltip https://quasar.dev/vue-components/tooltip to display text + image information.

How to prevent tooltip auto-disappear when mouse move on the tooltip? Currently, the tooltip disappears immediately when I move the mouse on it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use `v-model` and set the value to true in the `before-hide` event.

```html
<q-btn label="Hover me" color="primary">
  <q-tooltip @before-hide="beforeHide" v-model="show">
    Some text as content of Tooltip
  </q-tooltip>
</q-btn>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data: {
    show: false
  },
  methods: {
    beforeHide() {
      this.show = true;
    }
  }
})
```

https://codepen.io/pierresaid/pen/MWajrrV?editors=1011

https://quasar.dev/vue-components/tooltip#QTooltip-API

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS code below to disable quasar tooltip **no-pointer-events** class:

```
.no-pointer-events {
 pointer-events: all !important;
}
```

For example:

```
<template>
 <q-icon
  @mouseover="showTooltip"
  name="o_live_help"
  size="xs"
  class="icon"
 >
   <q-tooltip
   no-parent-event
   @mouseout="hideTooltip"
   v-model="tooltip"
   max-width="500px"
   transition-show="scale"
   transition-hide="scale"
   anchor="center middle"
   self="center middle"
   class="more glass text-on-dark"
 >
   <div class="text-body2 line-height q-pa-lg">
   {{ sampleText }}
   </div>
   </q-tooltip>
 </q-icon>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue"
const tooltip = ref(false)

const showTooltip = () => {
tooltip.value = true
}

const hideTooltip = () => {
tooltip.value = false
}

const sampleText = "Quasar is shit"

</script>

<style lang="scss">

.line-height {
line-height: 28px;
text-align: justify;
}

.no-pointer-events {
pointer-events: all !important;
}

</style>
```